# Negative calculation

Tags: cognito-forms

In my form, I am trying to do a simple sum calculation: `=Field1+Field2`, but by default, without even entering anything into these fields, the Sum calculation views as = ($14.00) meaning it's accounting for a negative -14.00$ somewhere and I have no clue where that's coming from.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is the calculation causing the issue: `=(NumberOfMilesDriven-25)*.56`.  If nothing is specified for the mileage, this will result in ($14.00).  Try one of these two alternatives:

1. `=Math.Max(NumberOfMilesDriven-25)*.56, 0)`
2. `=NumberOfMilesDriven > 25 ? (NumberOfMilesDriven-25)*.56 : 0`

Both of these will return $0.00 when the mileage is below 25 miles.